# Upload file and JSON data in the same POST request using jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, upload

I am trying to send a POST request using jQuery Ajax, where I would like to upload a file and some json data. Please find code,

```js
var logoImg = $('input[name="logoImg"]').get(0).files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('logo', logoImg);

var objArr = [];
objArr.push({
  "id": id,
  "name": userName
});

var obj = [{
  "objArr": objArr,
  "formData": formData
}];

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(obj),
  contentType: "application/json",
  cache: false,
  async: false,
  complete: function(data) {
    alert("success");
  }
});
```

But I am getting `Internal server error: 500` and the backend API is not called.

Please help me to send a file and an array obj in same AJAX request. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

You cannot serialise any binary data you send in the request.

To send additional information with the `FormData` object, just use the `append()` method to add it, similar to how you are with the image itself:

```js
var logoImg = $('input[name="logoImg"]').get(0).files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('logo', logoImg);
formData.append('id', id);
formData.append('name', userName);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  cache: false,
  complete: function(data) {
    alert("success");
  }
});
```

Note the important parts in the options are setting `contentType` and `processData` to `false`, and removing `async: false` so that the request occurs asynchronously.

Finally, note that if the inputs you want to send in the request are all contained within the same form you can use the `FormData` constructor to simplify your code to just:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#yourForm')[0]);
```

Comment: That's correct. It's FormData. You could send JSON in one of the properties if you really wanted to, eg. `formData.append('json', JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }));`

Comment: ok but, i received the data in this Post Variable in vardump i get this: `array(1) {
  ["jsonData"]=>
  string(166) "[{"s-file[]":"Prueba 3"},{"text_file[]":"Sistema.jpg"},{"idform":"f-gen-desk"},{"idprocess":"p-save"}]"
}` When i Try to decode i get null

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question then, as that issue seems unrelated to this question.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614446/post-can-conver-array-with-object-to-json

Comment: How to access it then now on server side?

Comment: @Biku7 that would depend entirely on what language you're using to build the server side system, but in short the mechanism to access the data would be the same as any other HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

**Example:-**

**  let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', input.files[0], input.files[0].name);**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/yourroute',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(res){
        console.log('successfully')
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error')
    }
})
```